# What have I to do to correctly set up XDebug? I am using XAMPP and PhpStorm as IDE. Doubts about php.ini content

Tags: php, apache, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am absolutly new in **PHP** (I came from Java) and I am trying to set up XDEBUG on my PHP environement.

I am using **XAMPP** for the LAMP environment and **PhpStorm** as IDE so I am following this tutorial:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-xdebug.html#d45497e21

**XAMPP** put the xdebug DLL  into this folder: **C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll**

So I am at stage 3 of the previous tutorial (**To enable Xdebug, locate the [Xdebug] section in the php.ini file and update it as follows**).

This is what I have add at the end of my **php.ini** file:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<AMP home\tmp>"
```

First I have set the location of the xdebug dll. Then I have set the port as 9000.

I don't know how to set the last line, this:

```
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<AMP home\tmp>"
```

What is it? what represent? What kind of value have I to put here? (I think that it is a path but what?)

Then I have another doubt. Going forward with the previous tutorial it say that I have to do another step into this **php.ini** file, it says:

> To enable multiuser debugging via Xdebug proxies, locate the
>   xdebug.idekey setting and assign it a value of your choice. This value
>   will be used to register your IDE on Xdebug proxy servers.

What exaclty is this **Xdebug proxies**? and why have I have to enable **multiuser debugging** ? What is it?

It say that I have to locate the **xdebug.idekey** setting in my **php.ini** file. But I have not this setting in my **php.ini** file. So what have I to do? Can I simply add it at the end of my **php.ini** file? What kind of value have I to set to it?

Comment: profiler_output_dir is the directory you want xdebug profiler to store profile output logs. It can be anything you want. You can safely add the idekey setting, it can be any string (ie "phpstorm"). In the PhpStorm settings you will find an input for xdebug idekey - enter the same key here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install/configure multi user proxy. This is only nessesary if you have a Development envirement for multiple Users on the same Development Server.

MultiUser Proxy (simplified):

The multiuser Proxy is a layer between your IDE and your XDebug instance. Every request from the XDebug instance connecting to this Proxy and is then forwarded/backedup to the correct user.

Check you PHP configuration if Xdebug is enabled. Put in your index file:

`echo php_info();`

Then search for Xdebug and check if it's activated. 
Then you shoud see the default idekey and your configuration.

The xdebug.idekey you can set to any that you wan't. It's a string. You must only check that you set the same key in your IDE and your Xdebug configuration.